# Recursive Binary Search Tree Trimming.. x=change(x)

Tags: java

This is what my code should do :
[image]

The problem requests that I create method accepts minimum and maximum integers as parameters and removes from the tree any elements that are not within that range, inclusive.

The code I initially wrote up was

```
public void trim (int min, int max) {
    overallRoot = trim (overallRoot, min, max);
}

private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root != null) {
        if(root.data < min && root.data > max) {
            root = null;
        }else {
            root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
            root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
        }
    } 
    return root;
}
```

and I did a little searching because my code doesn't rebuild the tree, I found this code:

```
private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
    root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
    if(root.data < max && root.data> min) {
        return root;
    }else if (root.data < min) {
        return root.right;
    }else if (node.data > max) {
        return root.left;
    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile because it is missing a return statement so, when I changed it to make it an else it only works in some cases. I somewhat understand the code above but it's not written very intuitively, but then again... recursion isn't very intuitive . "Take a leap of faith" as my professor says. Any help would greatly be appreciated :) Trying to do well on my final

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that even if the root node is outside the interval, its children needn't be, yet you remove the entire subtree regardless.

The code you found adresses this by first trimming the subtrees, and then looking at the root node. If it is left of `min`, both the root node and its left subtree must be removed, and the right subtree (which has already been trimmed) is what remains. Analogously, if the root is right of `max`, so is the right subtree, and the (already trimmed) left subtree is what needs to remain. This will visit the entire tree, and is therefore not very efficient.

A straightforward improvement would only visit the subtrees we intend to use:

```
private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    if(root.data < max && root.data> min) {
        root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
        root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
        return root;
    }else if (root.data < min) {
        return trim (root.right, min, max);
    }else if (node.data > max) {
        return trim(root.left, min, max);
    }
}
```

However, this still isn't optimal, because it revisits all nodes in [min, max].

Probably the best approach is to do the trimming in two steps: First trim all the nodes < min, then all the nodes > max:

```
IntTreeNode trimLeft(IntTreeNode root, int min) {
    if (root == null {
        return null;
    } else if (root.data < min) {
        return trimLeft(root.right, min);
    } else {
        root.left = trimLeft(root.left, min);
        return root;
    }
}
```

This approach has the advantage that we only visit the nodes on the path to `min` and `max`. If the search tree is balanced, this will be O(log n).

Irrespective of the approach you choose, you should correctly define what happens in the edge cases `root.data == min` and `root.data == max` (both your original code and the code you found do this wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your code covers all the cases for your recursion.

```
private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
    root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
    if(root.data < max && root.data> min) {
        return root;
    }else if (root.data < min) {
        return root.right;
    }else if (node.data > max) {
        return root.left;
    }
}
```

So let's list what it's checking:

- root is null
- min < current value < max
- current value < min
- max < current value

It's not covering the `current value == min` and `current value == max` cases! You said it should be checking for *inclusive* ranges. That means `min < current value < max` should be `min ≤ current value ≤ max`, right? I think that'll fix it.

However, like you said, the code isn't very readable. I'd change it a bit:

```
private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    // Base case: leaves' children are null
    if (root == null)
        return root;
    // Case: current value too small - use trimmed right subtree
    if (root.data < min)
        return trim(root.right, min, max);
    // Case: current value too large - use trimmed left subtree
    else if (node.data > max)
        return trim(root.left, min, max);
    // Case: current value in range - trim both subtrees
    else if (min <= root.data && root.data <= max) {
        root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
        root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
        return root;
    }
    // Make sure we've covered all the cases
    // (this should be unreachable if our cases are complete)
    throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled case in trim!");
}
```

This is a bit more efficient since you don't call `trim` on subtrees that you end up trimming away. I did duplicate a tiny bit of code by repeating the calls to `trim` in the last case, which some people might take issue with, but I personally think it's fine.

*(Note: I haven't actually tested any of this code, so it might have syntax errors and not even compile, but it should give you an idea of how this should work.)*

---

*In response to your comment:*

The code should run now since I added a `throw` clause to the end of the method.

Your code's `if (root != null)` clause is basically the same as the `if (root == null) return root;` case in the 2nd version.

`if (root.data < max && root.data > min)` is checking if the value is in the range *min thru max* **exclusive**.

So you're throwing away the entire subtree if the current node's value isn't between min and max, exclusive. You need to fix the code to only throw away the correct subtree, and to do an **inclusive** check.

---

On an aside, I think `if (min <= root.data && root.data <= max)` is much more readable than what you have because it looks more like what you'd write out in a more traditional math definition: `min ≤ root.data ≤ max`. It's nice to keep the inequality signs facing the same direction in my opinion.

Comment: @this1lefty - Does your code cover all the cases in the recursion? _(Hint: it doesn't.)_ You'll need to add code to handle all the same cases covered in the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: I understood what you wrote initially, I was simply stating about my first chunk of code because its written differently from the code I found, which is the one you are critiquing. Also that chunk of code online doesn't run because it is missing a return.

Comment: hmm. did you change your initial post lol ? I swear it wasn't as long and i was responding to that. And if i knew how to write the rest of the code i wouldn't be posting haha

Comment: @this1lefty — See my update, I think it answers your question. And yes, I edited my answer. You should see a thing down at the bottom of the answer saying the last time I made an edit.

Comment: @this1lefty – There was a mistake in my update (I had your logic backwards and thought there was a contradiction—oops!). I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works for all cases, for future people who end up google searching this problem haha:

```
public void trim (int min, int max) {
    overallRoot = trim (overallRoot, min, max);
}

private IntTreeNode trim (IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root == null) {
        return root;
    }
    if(root.data <= max && root.data>= min) {
        root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
        root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
        return root;
    }else if (root.data < min) {
        return trim (root.right, min, max);
    }else if (root.data > max) {
        return trim(root.left, min, max);
    }else{
        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void trim(int min, int max) {
    overallRoot = trim(overallRoot, min, max);
}

private IntTreeNode trim(IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root != null) {
        root.left = trim(root.left, min, max);
        root.right = trim (root.right, min, max);
        if (root.data < min) {
            return root.right;
        } else if (root.data > max) {
            return root.left;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Pretty intuitive. Since the binary tree is built in a way that the value on the left is always smaller or equal to the value in the root and the value in the right is always greater, if root.data is smaller than the min value, return the right branch (which will always be greater than root.data) and if the root.data is greater than the given max, return the left branch (which will always be smaller or equal). Use recursion to trim the entire tree (a binary tree consistes of two sides, left and right): trim(root.left, min, max) trim(root.right, min max). And return root to replace overallRoot which gives a tree with only values within the given min and max (inclusive).

More comprehensive structure:

```
public void trim(int min, int max) {
    overallRoot = trim(overallRoot, min, max);
}

private IntTreeNode trim(IntTreeNode root, int min, int max) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (root.data < min) {
            root = trim(root.right, min, max);
        } else if (root.data > max) {
            root = trim(root.left, min, max);
        } else {
            root.left  = trim(root.left,  min, max);
            root.right = trim(root.right, min, max);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```